# How to get the channelid or name of a newly created channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a command with my discord bot to make a channel, but I'm trying to figure out how to get the id or name of the channel right after its made.

Line of code that makes the channel:

`message.guild.channels.create('ticket ' + message.member.displayName, { parent: '744477882730020965' });`

The reason is that since displayname can have characters not possible in a channel name and discord will just automatically remove those characters there's no actual way to predict what the channel name will be in some cases. There's probably a simple solution I'm missing, and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`GuildChannelManager#create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) method returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with the channel that was just created. You can use [`Promise.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to get the channel.

```js
Guild.channels.create(`ticket-${message.member.displayName}`, {
    parent: "744477882730020965"
}).then(channel => {
    message.channel.send(`I've created the channel ${channel.name}!`);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    message.channel.send(`Couldn't create the channel. Check the console for the error.`);
});
```

---

If you are creating the channel in an `async function`, you can use `await` to avoid `.then()` for readability.

```js
const Channel = await Guild.channels.create(`ticket-${message.member.displayName}`, {
    parent: "744477882730020965"
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    message.channel.send(`Couldn't create the channel. Check the console for the error.`);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you need the ID for? You can use a then function to do whatever to edit the channel.

Try this?

```
let role = message.guild.roles.find("name", "@everyone");

message.guild.channels.create('ticket ' + message.member.displayName, { parent: '744477882730020965' }).then(c => {
c.overwritePermissions(role, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            READ_MESSAGES: false
        });
        c.overwritePermissions(message.author, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            READ_MESSAGES: true
        });
message.reply(`Application created!`)
c.send(`Wait for support staff`)
}).catch(console.error);
```